# Multiple catch clause does not catch at the more specific exception type

Tags: c#, try-catch

I've tried utilising the try-catch block with multiple catch clauses so that depending on the Exception type, there can be dedicated catch logic for different types of Exceptions.

I've placed the more specific exception type at the top (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException) to the more generic type at the bottom (Exception). However the code that is executed, even is always the most generic Exception catch clause even when the exception type matches System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException.

My code is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Bank bank)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Banks.Add(bank);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e)
        {
            return View("Error", e);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return View("Error", e);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Banks");
    }
```

I tried raising the exception without the try-catch block and indeed the exception is of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Let me know why this is the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

So I found something. I tried running with code (removing the generic Exception catch block):

```
    public ActionResult Create(Bank bank)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Banks.Add(bank);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e)
        {
            return View("Error", e);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Banks");
    }
```

When debugging, I got the following popup, showing the exception raised is actually of type `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException`.
[image]

When I continue the debug, the exception is thrown as the catch exception type is not satisfied. However on the site page, it shows in the exception detail that its of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`. So my catch block should catch this exception but the page and the debugger are showing different exception types.
[image]

I've tried debugging by changing the code to use the exception type the debugger reported, by using `catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException e)`, and as you can see on the debugging screen that now the catch block is being run.
[image]

Lol, so I still don't know why the debugger and the page are showing different exception types and why only the type shown in the debugger works. Let me know if you know anything but my original problem has been solved.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Q: Did you set breakpoints in both "catch" blocks to verify that it's NOT hitting the 1st block?

Comment: You have the same code in both catch blocks. How do you tell the difference? If this exact code is running on the machine and you have set a breakpoint into the first catch block and hit it - then please do a clean rebuild, copy the binaries again, restart visual studio etc. I'm 99,9% sure that this exception will get caught properly and you have the wrong binary or a debugging/IDE issue.

Comment: unrelated - If the handling of both exceptions is same, why separate catch?

Comment: *Let me know why this is the case* - it is not the case, unless you can show me something more convincing, such as a screenshot of the debugger stopped on a breakpoint in the `catch(Exception` handler, with the locals window clearly showing that `e` is a SqlException

Comment: Hi, so both catch blocks have the same code currently but I've used breakpoints to see exactly which block gets hit. I found only `catch(Exception e)`. If I comment out catch block for `catch(Exception e)`, then the exception gets thrown without getting caught by `catch(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e)`